# Trouble grasping the dp unit in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

So, I have googled a lot, but still cant quiet grasp the concept. I have 3 folders : xhdpi, lhdpi and mhdpi. I do understand the conversion and downscaling to different dip and screen densities. Android selects resources for the right screen type when the application runs.

But, how do I start? I made a background for my application in Photoshop. The background was defined in 720x1080px and exported as an .png file. I put the .png in the xhdpi folder. Everything worked out fine on my Sony Xperia Z, but when a friend loaded it on his Galaxy 3 the background was "to-small" and did not fit his screen. I assume this is because the bacground was to small.

But how large do I need to make it? What px-sizes should xhdpi drawable resources be to fit every single xhdpi screen?

Would a good approach be to start with the largest size, xhdpi? And then convert the drawables down to mdpi and ldpi later on? If so, I need a starter size in **px** so I can create the background for the application in Photoshop.

Here is how I use the background : (Note, i changed my height to fill_parent it fixed the "not filling the whole screen problem")

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_xhdpi" >
     </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You may wish to edit your question to explain **completely and precisely** how you are using this "background" image. Also, please bear in mind that neither the Xperia Z nor the Galaxy 4 are `-xhdpi` devices (both have 1080p screens that qualify for `-xxhdpi`). Of course, since AFAIK the Galaxy 4 is not shipping yet, it is unclear how your friend obtained one.

Comment: Typo there, its the Galaxy 3 ;). Well, I do understand the concepts.. or xxhdpi makes my cry inside. But still, it doesent explain the basic question, all graphics needs to be created in some way or another, I choose Photoshop to design with, and Photoshop needs px, not dp. The main question is how big should a, xxhdpi be? In px? Or am I thinking about it wrong?

Comment: You may wish to edit your question to explain **completely and precisely** how you are using this "background" image. What is this the background of? How are you controlling the size of whatever it is that it is the background of?

Comment: There you go, fixed height to "fill_parent" took care of the issue. But still im wondering about if my 720x1080px bg is big enough to show as good quality on all screens.

Answer (score 1):

To make PX sizes scale appropriately you will need to scale using the following ratios:

2X for XDPI

1.5X for HDPI

1X for MDPI (baseline

.75X for LDPI

When you are specifying sizes in your code (or XML), use the DP parameter to specify the value (or SP if you are specifying fonts).
for example: `android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"`

Here is the docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html, you will notice this image, and a lot of other details describing this.

[image]

Comment: Yep, but I have to start with something. Lets say I start with the background in XHDPI size. How big would I have to make the document in Photoshop then? In px? I could then scale it down to hdpi,mdpi and idpi later.

Comment: Pic a size - maybe xhdpi.  Setup your photoshop to match that resolution (1280 x 900 - or whatever it is).  Put your image in (sized however you want) - maybe it is 96 x 96.  Then scale the rest of your images appropriately (so hdpi in this case would be 72 x 72)

Answer (score 0):

You can find in [this table](http://checkscreensize.appspot.com/listdevice.jsp) a briefing of different devices screen densities and resolutions; according to it, Galaxy SIII is xhdpi with a resolution of 1280 X 720. Besides, you could want considerate to follow [compatibility mode guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html) to avoid rendering issues in multiple screens.